# Installed Tesseract 4.1.0 on Windows but --version in cmd is showing version 3.05.00dev

Tags: windows, tesseract

As the title says I installed Tesseract version 4.1.0 which is also shows under apps and features but when I type tesseract `--version` in `cmd` it shows `3.05.00dev`

according to this tutorial:

```
https://medium.com/quantrium-tech/installing-and-using-tesseract-4-on-windows-10-4f7930313f82
```

it should show at least 4.0

then I uninstalled Tesseract and typed tesseract --version in cmd and it still shows up as `3.05.00dev` but I can't find anything when I search for "tesseract" on the hdd.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simple means you have another installation of tesseract (3.05.00dev) somewhere and you need to [uninstall it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uninstall-or-remove-apps-and-programs-in-windows-10-4b55f974-2cc6-2d2b-d092-5905080eaf98).

If you can not find it in installed app, try this command in `cmd`:

```
where tesseract
```

It should reveal you where is tesseract installed and just remove it.

Comment: Nice! Can you also tell how to tell windows not to use this one? Like removing/editing registry or something?

Comment: I would also vote up your answer if you can tell

Comment: AFAIK windows is looking at path for program (and libraries), and use first found item. E.g. You need to adapt you PATH environment variable according your preference. BTW having 2 different installed version of tesseract is and will cause you just problem. Uninstall old/unused it the only right solution